# Can the Antenna Factor of a passive antenna be improved by adding a pre-amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, antenna, emc

If so what are the main considerations with respect to the noise of the amplifier?

Comment: In a word no...

Comment: No.  Antenna factor is a function of the antenna itself (shape, frequency, etc), and is independent of what it is attached to (assuming everything is matched).

Comment: I've rolled back the question to how it originally was phrased. Please note that if you need to ask a different question, editing your original question is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

For a very short receiving antenna, a high impedance preamplifier can reduce the load effect of the feed and thus increase the voltage for a given field. Amplifier voltage noise is of course a concern, as is amplifier input current noise. The current noise produces noise voltage via the high impedance of the antenna. Optimization involves estimating the signal to noise implications of the amplifier input impedance as a load along with the effects of voltage and current noise.

Answer (score 0):

"One misconception is that using an active reduced-size antenna or connecting a low noise amplifier to a passive reduced-size antenna will lower the noise floor and increase sensitivity. However, this is only true in a chamber environment where the noise floor is generally low. In a non-chamber environment, the low noise amplifier amplifies both ambient noise and the signal being measured. As a result, the spectrum analyzer will beep constantly due to RF input overloading. Therefore, reduced-size antennas are always inferior to full-size antennas in terms of performance in the lower frequency range."

https://incompliancemag.com/article/in-situ-radiated-emission-testing-of-large-systems-installations/

So works in theory but difficult in practice.

Edit:

Original question asked if antenna factor can be improved with amplifier. It cannot because AF is an intrinsic property of an antenna and is basically a transfer function treating the antenna as a transducer that converts EM to V. For this reason the concern about the limits to dynamic range of measurements is separate, not entirely but somewhat.

Comment: You don't appear to have answered your own question. You don't appear to understand what antenna factor is.

Comment: After having a think on it I changed the title of the question. What I wanted to know is will I be able to measure weaker signals by adding an amplifier so that the dynamic range of my measurements (w.r.t the limit line) improves. The question was prompted almost entirely by a misunderstanding of what antenna factor was. I think it makes more sense now, feel free to tell me otherwise if it doesn't.

Comment: @Tony - You changed the whole meaning of the question, so that the comments by Andy and myself no longer make sense.  You would have been better, IMO, to just ask a new question.